# Does running a .bat file in Windows generates any system log?

Tags: windows, security, batch-file

I want to create a .bat file in Windows that receives a password and will call a custom utility to encrypt that password.

Is really important that the password sent to the .bat file as parameter is not logged anywhere.

My question is, if running a .bat file will create any system logs? anywhere? What if the .bat fails?

Are there any other better ways of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic answer is, "No, the running of batch files is not logged."  However, there is no guarantee on a given system that the information is not saved somewhere. Or to say that again without double negatives, it is possible on some system that the information could be saved. For example, there could be a custom command shell (possibly created by the "bad" guy) that does log information.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a recommended way to prevent the "bad guys" from getting that information? For example, a security check that prevents the script from running on custom command shells?

Comment: @Javier: I don't know if there is a recommended way.  You could specify the path to the desired command processor (e.g., c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe). But still there is no guarantee that would be safe.  On the other hand, if the system has been compromised then all bets are off anyway; a process could be reading your process memory for that matter.  So it may not be overly prodcutive worrying about the "bad" guy scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to see the command line in the process list. So if something is logging processes, or if it's long-running and someone opens the Task Manager, they could see it.

Comment: That means that they would see my script running. But does that also means that a process logger could see the actual non-encrypted password? Is that even possible?

Comment: They would see that it is running, but the Task Manager wouldnt display what the process is doing, and so shouldnt show the password in anyway

Comment: If you're on Windows Vista/7/2008/2008R2, your Task Manager's Processes tab will show you the command line. (edit: View menu, Select Columns, turn on the Command Line column.) If you start a program with the password as a command line argument, it'll show up there.